# I want to display the data in Gridview from database in PHP

Tags: php, date, gridview, calendar

I am making project in PHP of meeting scheduling system and in that i had a problem to display the upcoming-meeting from database so that the user will get update of meting, and i had use table tag to display the content in gridview .

But i am fail to update Gridview daily and automatically of Upcoming-meeting according to the current date of system so that it will display the meeting from current date to upcoming-date and previous booked meeting should not display in GridView.

Any solution will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What you have done yet ?

Comment: i had a gridview which fetch the data from database and display it. but i want a query that it will display  the meeting of today date to further upcoming days.